# What are the values of an array obtained from base64

Tags: javascript, base64

I have an image in base64 notation. Which I can convert into an array

```
var byteCharacters =  atob(base64);
var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);

for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

Copied the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript). When I output the array I see

```
[ 137,
  80,
  78,
  71,
  13,
  10,
  26,
  10,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  13,
  73,
  72,
  68,
  82,
  ...
```

What are these numbers, is it RGB colors ? Like

```
byteNumbers[0] --> Red
byteNumbers[1] --> Green
byteNumbers[2] --> Blue
byteNumbers[3] --> Red
```

But how do I get info about rows/columns ? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Those numbers are the individual bytes of the raw image data (since you're talking about what you have *after* passing it through `atob`). Their meaning will depend on what kind of image it is — JPEG, GIF, BMP, TIFF, etc.

How you decode the byte stream to determine image dimensions, colors of individual pixels, etc. is very different from format to format.

Comment: Thnx. its a screenshot from within a selenium webdriver.  I think it is png, because I can save it as `out.png` :) Is there a way to get the pixels/colors ?